# Flutter how to connect a socket?

Tags: sockets, dart, flutter

Flutter how to connect to a socket, which I write a Python script as a server, this server side is like this:

```
import socket
import time


sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
sock.bind(("192.168.0.113", 9999))# 注意bind的这里，IP地址和端口号都要与前面的程序中一样
sock.listen(2)# 监听端口

# 等待数据源端连接
src, src_addr = sock.accept()
print "Source Connected by", src_addr

# 等待目标端连接
dst, dst_addr = sock.accept()
print "Destination Connected by", dst_addr

while True:
    msg = src.recv(1024 *1024)
    if not msg:
        break
    try:
        dst.sendall(msg)
    except Exception as ex:
        dst, dst_addr = sock.accept()
        print "Destination Connected Again by", dst_addr
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print "Interrupted"
        break

src.close()
dst.close()
```

I wanna using Flutter to write a very simple client to show the image send from this python server via socket, how to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know about raw sockets but if you can use WebSockets in Python you could use the [web_socket_channel](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/web_socket_channel) package:

```
import 'package:web_socket_channel/io.dart';
import 'package:web_socket_channel/status.dart' as status;

main() async {
  var channel = await IOWebSocketChannel.connect("ws://localhost:1234");

  channel.stream.listen((message) {
    channel.sink.add("received!");
    channel.close(status.goingAway);
  }, onDone: () => print("Stream closed"));
}
```

There's more info on using this here:

https://flutter.io/cookbook/networking/web-sockets/

Comment: Hi, sir. do u know how to listen the disconnection callback in flutter as well? It would be great if can add to this answer so that anyone else can get a full picture relate to these question.

Comment: I haven't tested it, but you should be able to use the `onDone` parameter of the `listen` method (`onDone: () => print("Stream closed")`). I've added to the answer to show where it would go.

Comment: i have a url like this "ws://174.01.01.01:1000" and get error Insecure HTTP is not allowed by platform, how i can fix this?